# Прежде всего — не вводное сочетание, но просит отделения из-за паузы

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

В предложении «**Автор поднимает ряд проблем человеческих отношений(,) прежде всего в процессе обучения**» очень хочется поставить обозначенную запятую. Можно?

Comment: Да ставь смело, авторской будет называться. Безо всякого "и" и тире. Можно. Присоединение-уточнение. ***«Автор поднимает ряд проблем человеческих отношений, прежде всего в процессе обучения».*** То есть означенный автор говорит о ряде проблем в отношениях, но самые главные ("прежде всего") - те, что возникают в процессе обучения.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova спасибо! :)

Comment: Я там дописала - уложилась в редактирование! )))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova вы точнее всех поймали мою мысль; напишите ответ, что ли, дам баллов! )

Comment: А ничего, если я сворую ответ из коммента? Баллов оченно хочется!

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova ничего )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жасмин говорит о присоединительном союзе ***прежде всего*** на основе присоединительного союза ***и***, но ведь, как и подразумеваемое противопоставление (при слитном-раздельном "не"), он, союз ***и***, тоже может подразумеваться.

Так что желанная запятая *авторская,* как я указала в комменте, только отчасти: она вполне оправдана правилом.

Причем безо всякого ***и*** и тире. Знаки препинания - это дыхание автора: пишет как дышит. "Как он дышит, так и пишет, не стараясь угодить..."

*«Автор поднимает ряд проблем человеческих отношений, прежде всего в процессе обучения».* То есть означенный автор говорит о ряде проблем в отношениях, но самые главные ("прежде всего") - те, что возникают в процессе обучения.

Comment: Я бы тоже поставила запятую (чисто интуитивно). Присоединяюсь к Вашему объяснению и оцениваю соответственно.

Comment: Римулик, пасибки! )))

Answer (score 2):

В качестве варианта с небольшим редактированием:

**Автор поднимает ряд проблем человеческих отношений, и прежде всего ―  в процессе совместного обучения.**

**Автор поднимает ряд проблем человеческих отношений, и прежде всего ― проблем  при совместном обучении.**

Примеры:

Но главная борьба и соперничество разворачиваются за энергетические ресурсы, **и прежде всего** ― за нефтяные источники.

Необходимо, на его взгляд, произвести модификацию принципов учёта в государственном секторе, **и прежде всего** ― принципа начисления.

Comment: Спасибо! А чем здесь оправдана запятая перед *и*? Авторская?

Comment: И ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО - составной присоединительный союз, на основе присоединительного союза И.

Answer (score 1):

Остается неясным, *поднимает в процессе* или *проблем в процессе*.

Мой вариант:

**Автор поднимает ряд проблем человеческих отношений, и прежде всего ― (проблем,) возникающих в процессе обучении.**

Answer (score 0):

«Отношений в процессе обучения». Здесь не нужна запятая, как и в более расширенном вашем предложении.

Comment: Я понимаю, что не надо, но — хочется ведь! Ни под каким предлогом нельзя поставить?

Comment: Нельзя. Если хочется: «Проблем человеческих отношений, прежде всего возникших в процессе обучения.»

Comment: Казенно, но вполне возможно. Спасибо!

Comment: Но в исходном варианте другой смысл: "поднимает прежде всего там-то" (остальное грамматически рассогласовнао). Я бы при таком смысле поставил запятую (отделение уточняющего оборота) и после "всего" - тире, поскольку глагол "поднимает" далековато и его надо заместительно "освежать".